# Errors installing Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, installation, syntax-error

I am trying to install beautiful soup on my laptop. I am running python 3.4.3 and installing bs4-4.3.2

I extracted the file, opened a command window, and ran the setup file from the command line. But it did not seem to be installed in the lib\site-packages file, so I copied and pasted it into there, and the lib file itself. When I go to run bs4, it is giving me syntax errors left and right. Is this not the right version for python 3?

Comment: Why not just `pip install bs4`? Or `python3 -m pip install bs4`

Comment: Manually installing like this (unless specified) is a really, really, really, really, really bad idea because it will result in issues exactly like this. Please just use `pip` instead - it is a package manager, is designed to solve issues like this across all platforms, and is the industry standard.